# Shift-Tab produces cryptic error in Emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs23, org-mode

I'm trying to learn `org-mode` and noticed my files are folded neatly when I exit emacs. When pressing `S-TAB` in an attempt to unfold the entire file, I get the following error message in the mini-buffer: `M-[ z is undefined`. Googling the error wasn't helpful. Any idea where the hiccup is occurring and how I might fix it?

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.4 with Terminal.app, GNU Emacs 23.2.1.

**Edit:** I can confirm now that the problem is Terminal.app. I do not receive this error message using Carbon Emacs or when using Emacs from within iTerm.app.

Thanks to Gilles for patiently walking me through a solution.

Comment: What does <kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> show? (or `M-x describe-key S-Tab`)

Comment: Both return `M-[ z (translated from M-[ Z) is undefined` in the mini-buffer.

Comment: Hmm... I just ran into this in an 'emacsclient -nw' window in a GNU screen session.  I used C-x C-c to detach the window to get back to the shell prompt (with emacs --daemon still running in the background).  Then I opened a new emacslient window and S-tab worked fine.  I re-attach the screen session from various terminals (gnome-terminal, xterm, cygwin mintty) depending on the platform I happen to be on.  I can't say I tracked down the root cause, but opening a new 'emacsclient -nw' window "fixed" it in my case.  emacs-24.5.  Seems in my case to be a temporary key mapping mixup (not sure how)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The interface between the terminal and the program running inside it (here, Emacs) can only send characters, not keys. So special keys or key combinations often send a key sequence beginning with `ESC`. For example, your terminal apparently sends `ESC [ Z` for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Normally Emacs translates these character sequences back into key names, but it seems that the developers missed this one. You can define it yourself with

```
(add-hook 'term-setup-hook
          (lambda () (define-key input-decode-map "\e[Z" [backtab])))
```

(For Emacs <= 22, just use `(define-key function-key-map  "\e[Z" [backtab])`.)

Some modes may define bindings for `S-tab` and not `backtab`. If you have Emacs 23, `(define-key function-key-map [S-tab] [backtab])` should make these modes work.

Comment: We need an extra end-parend for the Emacs 23 code. Neither one seems to fix my issue. Emacs is still throwing the error with both of those lines in my `.emacs` file.

Comment: It is probably better to use [backtab] rather than [S-tab]. At least in Emacs 23, that seems to be the canonical name that S-tab, iso-left-tab and other variations are mapped to.

Comment: @JSON: Thanks, indeed most modes have bindings for `backtab` now. @jrhorn424: do you still get exactly the same error message? What if you manually evaluate `(define-key input-decode-map "\e[z" [backtab])`?

Comment: Yes, I still receive the same exact error. Manually evaluating the expression returns `[backtab]` in the mini-buffer. Pressing `S-TAB` after evaluating the expression returns the same error I've been receiving.

Comment: I changed my OP to reflect the fact that Terminal.app appears to be the culprit. It doesn't explain why the key-remapping isn't sticking.

Comment: @jrhorn424: Strange... If you go to the `*scratch*` buffer any type `(read-key-sequence "Type S-tab: ")` then `C-j` and then `S-tab` at the prompt, what is inserted in the scratch buffer? Another test: if you start emacs in Terminal.app with `TERM=xterm emacs -q -nw`, what happens if you press `S-tab`? What is the value of `$TERM` in Terminal.app?

Comment: The `*scratch*` test (te-hehe) returns `"^[[z"` into the buffer. In the terminal, `echo $TERM` returns `xterm-color`. When starting emacs using `TERM=xterm emacs -q -nw`, `S-tab` works as expected.

Comment: According to this [Backtab Howto][1], `^[[z` is a standard terminal sequence for `backtab`. I tried adding the lines from Step 3 to my `.emacs` to no avail.



  [1]: http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/user/daveg/Info/backtab-howto.txt

Comment: @jrhorn424: It seems that your terminal sends `ESC [ Z`, not `ESC [ z`. (That's the standard sequence by the way, as indicated in your reference.) Does it work if you use a capital Z in the Lisp code?

Comment: I'm using GNU emacs 22.1.1(I'm very new to emacs) and when I use this: `(define-key function-key-map "\e[Z" [backtab])` I get this error: `<backtab> is undefined`.  Any help?

Comment: @jonnyflash On what operating system? What if you use `S-tab` instead of `backtab`?

Comment: The main answer worked for me in Emacs 24.1.1:
(add-hook 'term-setup-hook
          (lambda () (define-key input-decode-map "\e[Z" [backtab])))

Answer (score 0):

Like the original poster, I'm using Mac OS X, but version 10.6.8 and GNU Emacs 23.4.1. I was experiencing the same issues with S-Tab and org-mode. I was able to resolve this by following the steps that were extremely helpful at: http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/user/daveg/Info/backtab-howto.txt

Comment: Please describe the steps instead of posting an URL